# How to unshallow a clone without unshallow?

Tags: git

I'm trying to reduce the history a la large repository. I made a shallow clone

```
git clone --depth --no-single-branch 1000 url
```

Then I checked all branches with this script

```
#!/bin/bash
for branch in `git branch -a | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master `; do
   git branch --track ${branch#remotes/origin/} $branch
done
```

After that, I've changed the origin

```
git remote add new-origin new-url
git remote rm origin
git remote mv new-origin origin
```

And then I made a push on the new repository. My problem is that system does not permit to push to a new repository a shallow clone. If I return to my old repository to unshallow with:

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

then the whole repo is synced again. Do you know a way to unshallow my clone without unshallow?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your repo is fetching from the new repo?  Maybe specifying the new repository explicitly in your fetch will help.

Comment: My bad, I've corrected my question.

Comment: Rather than "unshallow a clone without unshallow" which makes no sense, do you mean "Remove old history from a repository"? This can be done, but all the hashes will change. A shallow clone knows that history exists, it just doesn't know what it is. Could you update the title and body of this to not mention "(un)shallow".

Answer (score 5):

So here is what you want to do. Go ahead and clone the whole repo, or `fetch --unshallow`. Now, let's say the SHA of the commit you want as the root commit of your new repo is `abc123`. Do the following:

```
git checkout --orphan temp abc123
git commit -C abc123   #creates a root commit with the contents and commit message of abc123
git replace abc123 temp  #"tricks" git into using the root commit instead of `abc123`
git filter-branch -- --all  #rewrites the whole repo
git checkout master
git branch -D temp
```

Then you can push to your new remote repo.